# How Can I do “the same UPDATE-METHOD” updates 02 Collections “at the same time” using Spring Data ReactiveMongoTemplate?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, reactive-mongo-java

#### 1) Problem Description:

- I am using a Reactive Spring-Data + Spring WebFlux + MongoDb + ReactiveMongoTemplate;
- I have 02 Collections: ***Task*** and ***Project***

#### 2) My Goal is:

- Using only ***“one***  **update method”**
- that updates the 02 documents inside the 02 Collections *(at the same time - simultaneously)*

#### 3) Code:

##### 3.1)  Collection Task

```java
@Document(collection = "task")
public class Task {

  @Id
  private String _id;

  @Field("pid")
  private String projectId;

  private String taskName;

  private String ownerProject;
}
```

##### 3.2)  Collection Project

```java
@Document(collection = "project")
public class Project {
  @Id
  private String _id;

  private String ownerProject;

  private Task tasksProject;

  private String code;
}
```

##### 3.3)  My current code - which is not working

```java
 public Mono<Void> updateWithCriteriaTemplateMult(String id) {

    Query projectDocument = new Query();
    projectDocument.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id")
                                             .is(id));

    Query taskDocument = new Query();
    taskDocument.addCriteria(Criteria.where("projectId")
                                          .is(id));


    return template
         .update(projectDocument, Project.class)
         .then(template.update(taskDocument, Task.class))
         ;
  }
```

---

#### 2) Question:

- How Can I code/do “the same UPDATE-METHOD”  updates both Collections “at the same time” using ReactiveMongoTemplate?

  - Example 01: My method needs to “update” the field “ownerProject”  in both Collections:

    - Task: in this case ‘ownerProject’ is a simple field
    - Project: in this case ‘ownerProject’ is a simple field
- Example 02:

  - My method needs to “update” the field “taskName” in both Collections:

    - Task: in this case ‘TaskName’ is a simple field
    - Project: in this case ‘TaskName’ is field “inside” “tasksProject”

---

*Thanks a lot for any help*

Comment: How is it ”not working”? Please update with outcome, errors etc

Comment: Actually, there is no error message. 
Simply, the second Collection(Task) is not being updated, 
although, the first one(Project) is being updated. It is so strange...

Comment: why are you chaining so many `then`?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Opsss. my bad. it is corrected

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Thats my solution for this problem, using delete instead update (same idea):

```java
    public Mono<ProjectChild> DeleteCritTemplMultCollections(
       String projectId,
       String taskId) {

    Query project = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id")
                                        .in(projectId));

    Query taskToDelete = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id")
                                             .in(taskId));

    Update deleteTaskInProjectCollection = new Update();
    deleteTaskInProjectCollection.pull("tasks", taskToDelete);

    Mono<DeleteResult> removeTaskInTaskCollection =
         template.remove(taskToDelete, Task.class);

    return template
         .updateMulti(project, deleteTaskInProjectCollection, "projectchild")
         .then(removeTaskInTaskCollection)
         .then(template.findById(projectId, ProjectChild.class));
  }
```

For better understanding, follow There are my entities:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "projectchild")
public class ProjectChild {
  @Id
  private String _id;

  private String name;

  private String code;

  @Field("desc")
  private String description;

  private String startDate;

  private String endDate;

  @Field("cost")
  private long estimatedCost;

  private List<String> countryList;

  private List<Task> tasks;

  @Version
  private Long version;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "task")
public class Task {

  @Id
  private String _id;

  @Field("pid")
  private String projectId;

  private String name;

  @Field("desc")
  private String description;

  private String ownername;

  private long cost;

  @Version
  private Long version;
}
```